# Wordpress showing just the timestamp of first article

Tags: php, wordpress

my wordpress theme i created shows just the first timestamp of the first article of multiple article on the page. On the rest of them there is just a empty space, so php generated no echo.

I think that there is something wrong with the loop, but i found similar loops on the wp page. Can someone help me ? 
here is my code

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <div class="entry">
             <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
               <div class="time-text">added on: <?php the_date('d.m.Y'); ?> - Author: <?php the_author(); ?></div>

    <div id="text_post" style="margin-top:20px;">
                 <?php the_content(); ?> 
                       </div></div>
              <?php endwhile;endif?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how the [`the_date`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) function works.  Quoting the "special note" on that page:

> SPECIAL NOTE: When there are multiple posts on a page published under
>   the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post
>   (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for
>   posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag
>   the_time() or get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format
>   string.

Try using `<?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?>` instead of `<?php the_date('d.m.Y'); ?>`.  That's untested - I'm just going by that quote.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to open these three files:
index.php
single.php
page.php

Then you will need to locate the following code:

```
<?php the_modified_time('F jS, Y');?>
```

Note: Since there are so many formats of displaying dates, you might not see the exact code, but something along this line.
Replace it with:

```
<?php $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
echo "and last modified on "; 
the_modified_time('F jS, Y'); 
echo " at "; 
the_modified_time(); 
echo ", "; } ?>
```